# Alterar a posição de um Commandfield no gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sou iniciante e estou a tentar criar uma tabela dinâmica que dê para editar e apagar certos campos então decidi usar o gridview. O problema que não consigo resolver é a posição desse commandfield que eu criei para apagar, ele fica sempre na esquerda e o resto da tabela é alimentado dinamicamente pela base de dados.

UserEdit.aspx

```
<tbody id="tb" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" CssClass="table table-bordered">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="20" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  DeleteText="<img src='imagens/recyclebin-512.png'" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</tbody>
```

UserEdit.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = _sql.GetEditUtilizadores();
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Output:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para deixa-lo a direita, creio que deverá utilizar os BoundFields para cada campo.

Comment: Poderia explicar um pouco melhor? Qual é a diferença?

Comment: Está na resposta com exemplo de código ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro da sua TAG de `Columns` adicione os BoundFields, são campos já predefinidos no código, com isso você chega a perder um pouco da dinamicidade do Grid, mas acho que seja uma das saídas, e a que eu consegui pensar.

Ex.:

```
<Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="Id" HeaderText="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Nome" HeaderText="NOME" />
        <asp:CommandField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="20" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"  DeleteText="<img src='imagens/recyclebin-512.png'" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
</Columns>
```

> Ressalto que na propriedade `DataField` do `BoundField` você deve
>   colocar o mesmo nome da sua propriedade dentro da sua classe ou tabela, ou criar
>   coleções.

Você já deixa no código quais os campos seu grid aceitará, assim depois no `codebehind` defina como `Visible false` os campos cujos você não queira que apareça no determinado momento.
Ex.:

```
GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Espero ter ajudado, foi a única maneira que consegui pensar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Augusto, finalmente consegui entender o porquê de usar boundfields.